# Badges reset after email address update

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, profile-page, email

When I update my email address, it seems that my badges are reset, and then re-awarded based on my previous activity. However, it seems that this process isn't fully working as I had 9 badges before the email address update, and now have 6. For example, the "Informed" badge does not appear anymore. Is this the intended behavior, or is there an bug?

(Obviously this doesn't terribly matter from a practical perspective as I don't think people are here for the badges, but perhaps useful to point out a bug/feature)

**Edit:** it seems that there is some delay to the re-awarding of the badges. I now have 8 of my old badges, plus a new one ("Quorum") for this post. Including the "Quorum" badge, I should now have 10 badges, but only have 9. So (out of the badges that I've earned) the non-transfer bug/feature applies only to the "Informed" badge.

Comment: You'll be surprised the lengths people will go for badges.

Comment: _Dear diary, it has been 83 harsh days of logging into StackOverflow, but I managed to mess up one day and miss my chance for the fanatic badge for this month. Though, I shall not rest for I need to receive it_

Comment: Badges on meta are separated from badges on main.

Comment: If you read the entire tour page again, are you immediately awarded the "Informed" badge? Do you end up with two "Informed" badges?

Comment: @TinyGiant Quorum/Convention/... are given on the main site right, even though they're about your activity on Meta?

Comment: @g00glen00b no, your main account is a different acoount than your meta account. Badges, votes, flags, etc. are all separate.

Comment: @TinyGiant I got the Quorum badge on my main account for my post on meta. Also, reputation is transferred over from main to meta, so it does't look like they're entirely separate. In this post I am referring to my main account badges.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, there are a couple badges that are awarded on main for activity on meta, but the accounts are still separate. As you see, if you look at your meta account you only have 2 badges, but your main account has 9.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Updating your email address caused your profile to be merged into an older profile that already had the same verified email, because we do not allow multiple accounts to exist with the same email address.

When a merge occurs, badges are *not* transferred, so you start out with whatever badges you already had on the destination account, which in this case was the account with only a couple badges because we *always* merge into the lower user ID.

After the merge, the system will re-award all badges that you still qualify for over the next 24 hours. Each badge runs on different cycles, with tag badges taking the longest since they are only awarded once a day. If you've fallen below the requirements for any badge you had before, you will *not* receive it again until you qualify again.

As far as the Informed badge, I'm not sure we actually record anything on your profile that marks you as having received that badge. It's awarded instantly on the tour page and can be re-earned in about 2 seconds by just scrolling to the bottom of that page.

Comment: Does that mean that badges such as "Census", "Not a robot" etc are lost during a merge? If so, isn't it a design flaw?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski No, those all create database records somewhere that attach such an action to your account, which does get updated during a merge and would re-award the badge. Informed is the only badge awarded *instantly* in such a manner, and it's possible that we literally just add the badge to your profile without recording anywhere that you "completed an action" that could be read again later. It's just so pointless to do that.

Comment: Further, I'm not even sure there is a *process* that awards Informed badges that runs on a regular basis, given that they are always immediately awarded by looking at that page. Logically, there shouldn't be a reason to have a process for it.